# Как отменить отловленное исключение? Т.е. пробросить выше

Tags: php, исключения

```
    try {
        return parent::add($data);
    }
    catch(\Main\DB\SqlQueryException $e) {

       if($e->errorCode == 1) {
            Тут отменить обработку исключения, пробросить выше..
       }

    }
```

Как это сделать?

Проблема в том, что у экзепшена \Main\DB\SqlQueryException нет больше наследников.. Создать их нельзя, т.к. это ядро CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
throw $e;
```

`throw` требует чтобы ему дали объект исключения. Он не требует, чтобы было написано именно `throw new`.